# stm32 - Access to register of unclocked peripheral at 0x40010C10 cause BUS_FAULT [U1_CM3CORE]

Tags: stm32, keil, stm32f1

I'm working with STM32F103R6, tried to simulate blinking an LED but when I start the simulation Proteus 8 freezes and I got 9706 error messages "Access to register of unclocked peripheral at 0x40010C10 cause BUS_FAULT [U1_CM3CORE]" then simulation stops. I tried to change the frequency, simulation works fine but LED is not blinking neither lighting.
My code:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"     // Device header
 
 void gpioConfig(){
 
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIOInitStructure;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB,ENABLE);
     
    GPIOInitStructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIOInitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIOInitStructure.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
     
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB,&GPIOInitStructure);
     
 }
 
 void delay(uint32_t time){
 
     while(time--);
 
 }
 
 int main   (){

  gpioConfig();
    
    while(1){
      
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0);
        delay(36000000);
        
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0);
        delay(36000000);
            
  }

}
```

I tried to change the frequency but it just saved from crashing the Proteus 8. LED didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any code that would blink an LED. It's just setting it to the same value each time around the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from an address 0x40010C10, which is GPIOB Bit Set Reset Register (BSRR), and Bus Fault most likely means unaligned access or some other kind of problem during read/write, most likely write, since it's BSRR.

Therefore, I believe you have a problem with `GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0)` and/or `GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0)`. It could be that those functions write a 16-bit into a register that supports only 32-bit access, or perform some kind of unaligned access. While the M3 core itself allows unaligned access (with integers at least), the registers it works on don't always allow unaligned access and/or access of arbitrary width.

I couldn't find explicit information on what kind of access those GPIO registers support, but some registers of some peripherals support only aligned 32-bit access, so it's a theory that fits the evidence.

Look into `GPIO_SetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0)` and `GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOB,GPIO_Pin_0)`, they should have aligned 32-bit writes. If they have 16-bit writes, that could be the problem.